# Count down for next day in Hours

Tags: r

How to calculate the number of hours the clock needs to tick in order to complete the day

for e.g : Suppose the Datetime is 27/11/2017 16:30 at present, how to calculate the number of hours remaining to complete the day (for 28/11/2017 00:00 to begin)

Assuming that the Datetime is in Posixlt format.

Comment: Take a look at `difftime`. E.g. (with `x` being your first date and `y` your second) `difftime(y,x,unit="hours")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @count  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `unclass` on a POSIXlt, you get a structure that breaks out all of the components. The code below gives fractional hours. I am not sure how you want to deal with the partial hours.  Rounding?

```
T1 = unclass(strptime("27/11/2006 16:30", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
24 - (T1$hour + T1$min/60)
[1] 7.5
```

Comment: had no idea `unclass` got this accomplished. Thank you for the example @g5w

Comment: Thanks a lot in deed @G5W.. it worked exactly how i wanted it to. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I really like @G5W's answer above; here's an alternative, albeit convoluted way:
Steps:
1) Ensure we're in the `POSIXct` format
2) Add another day to whatever the initial time is
3) Break apart the time fields using `stringi`
4) Convert the `Hour,Minute,Second` fields into seconds
5) Subtract the numeric representation from the `next day` we created
6) subtract the variable time from that time.

```
> as.POSIXct(lubridate::dmy_hm('27/11/2017 16:30') + (60 * 60 * 24)) %>% {
    t <- stringi::stri_datetime_fields(.) %>% select(Hour, Minute, Second)
    (. - (t$Minute * 60 + (t$Hour * 60 * 60) + t$Second)) - dt
}
Time difference of 7.5 hours
```